# Set default to empty result with views exposed filters

Tags: 7, views

I am using Views (7.x-3.0-beta3) and I have created a exposed text filter to a view, which work fine.

The problem is the default result value: when the field is empty, is displaying all possible results. But I want to display the empty result by default. If you have a solution please shear it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a views preprocessor to achieve this. The 'empty' element behaves similarly to the "No Results Behavior" option in the Views UI. Place this code in template.php and clear the cache:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['view']->name == 'my_view_name') {
    if (empty($vars['view']->exposed_input)) {
      $vars['rows'] = array();
      $vars['empty'] = '';
    }
  }
}
```

Tested using Views 7.x-3.0-rc1.

Comment: I am having similar requirement. Where exactly should this code be added? can I add it in views.php?